# Count all rows in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am searching for a column in vba that has a certain header and then when I find that I want to search all the rows in that column and replace all the X's with 1's.  I have all the code written but for some reason its not allowing the line shown below:

```
r2 = Range(i, i).EntireColumn.Rows.Count



Sub PA_Change()

Dim i As Long, r As Range, rRow As Range, r2 As Long

Set r = Range("A1")
Set rRow = r.EntireRow

For i = 1 To rRow.Columns.Count

    If Cells(1, i) = PA_REQUIRED Then
        r2 = Range(i, i).EntireColumn.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To r2
        If Cells(j, i).Value = "X" Then
            Cells(j, i).Value = "1"
        End If
    Next j
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: The line I've put at the top. The whole macro (including that line) is then pasted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing all your code with this and let us know if that works:

*replace the `"boo"` in `searchFor` with the actual header name / `PA_REQUIRED`

```
Sub PA_Change()

    Dim searchFor As String
    searchFor = "boo"

    Dim grabColumn As Range
    Set grabColumn = Rows("1:1").Find(What:=searchFor, _
                     After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not grabColumn Is Nothing Then
        Dim entireColumn As Range
        Set entireColumn = Range(grabColumn.Address & ":" & Split(grabColumn.Address, "$")(1) & Range(Split(grabColumn.Address, "$")(1) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In entireColumn
            If UCase(cell) = "X" Then
                cell = "1"
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Exit Sub ' not found
    End If

End Sub
```